# .Net Core Project , Add Jquery Definitely Typed , $ sign not recognised in ts (Already added nugets)

Tags: jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, definitelytyped

Added nuget DefinitelyTyped

[image: reference]

tsconfig.json  added at rootlevel
[image]

**Jquery not detecting, How to add reference to make this work.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a [reference](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to the type def in your ts file (look at the `Working with Other JavaScript Libraries` section).

Also, if that doesn't work, try restarting VS.  And if that doesn't work, install the type def using NPM.  That's what I used, I had issues for some reason using Nuget Package Manager in VS.

**edit:**  According to DefinitelyTypes, all type defs have been turned off for Nuget: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#readme

Comment: I dont get it. What do I have to do, to be able to use jquery? Do I have to create the type definitions myself? That sounds crazy to me, but thats how I read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries .
NPM also seems like it doesnt like the @types/jquery package (it stays at not installed).

Comment: This is the correct answer but I didn't understand at first. You have to add the following comment to your .ts file:

/// <reference path="../jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

Of course, the path is wherever your file resides. I also had to manually copy over my jquery.d.ts file from C:\users\[user]\.nuget\packages\jquery.typescript.definitelytyped\3.1.2\Content\Scripts\typings\jquery